# Gradient of a scalar function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, scalar-fields

I have a scalar function $f = \lvert \underline{r} \rvert^n$ where $\underline{r} = (x,y,z)$. I have to find the gradient of the scalar function $f$ as a function of $\underline{r}$. This seems really abstract to me. How do I start?

Comment: Take some partial derivatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by making it less abstract.

Find the gradient of the following function using chain rule.

$$f(x,y,z) = \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{n/2}$$

Comment: Ah, I completely missed that. This makes it much clearer. Thank you!